# Run multiple jars on single command

Tags: java, jar, terminal, ubuntu-14.04

Is there anyway to run more than one executable JAR file in Ubuntu terminal ?

For ex: `java options -jar sample.jar {args}`

As of I knew, the above command will run single jar at a runtime.

Like above, there is any other way to run multiple jars at a single run.

For ex: `java options -jar sample.jar sample1.jar {args}`

I knew my above example is wrong. But I requests alternate suggestions...

Comment: How is that supposed to work? Every JVM process can have only a single entry-point (main method). And who gets the `{args}`? All of them? Why not run them separately? Do they need to run in the same process?

Comment: Or are you asking about how to add additional jar files (or class folders) to the classpath of an executable jar (so as to provide configuration or things like database drivers)?

Comment: I guess, you need to create a script with a single `java` command on each line.

Comment: @Thilo Actually I ll run thie jars using Python sub process module. The inputs for them are same but the work what they ll do, is different. Is any other options existing? Better than run separately ?

Comment: @Thilo Popen(['java', '-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8', '-jar', jar_path, args], stdout=False, stderr=False). I want to add one more jar to this process. I dont know how to add it in a single process.

Comment: You might as well ask how to run multiple programs of any kind, which makes this a general "how do I use a command line" question.